# How to add on-scroll navigation effect

Tags: html, css, navigation

This Website (http://www.madebyjoyce.com/) has a very beautiful navigation and it is enabled only after we scroll down to certain point. I was wondering if I could get a tutorial how to add this effect.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this gets you in the mood:

This is pretty much the deal, the rest you can do with css,

```
var scrollTop,viewportHeight;
$(window).scroll(function(e){
     scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    $('div:not(.visible)').each(function(){
        var top = $(this).offset().top;
        var bottom = top + $(this).height();
        if(top <= scrollTop && bottom >= (scrollTop + viewportHeight) ){
            $(this).addClass('visible');

        }else{
            console.log(scrollTop,top);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ErBRf/8/